# Parse/Creating Types in Python

Tags: python, types, type-conversion, tokenize

I'm trying to figure out how to create types and convert the users input according to those types. 
For example:

user enters: 5

5 is of type Number
5 gets added to the list

user enters: 3.5

3.5 is of type Number
3.5 gets added to the list

user enters: :true:

:true: is of type Boolean
:true: gets added to the list

I want my program to to be able to convert the number 5 to an int then put it on the stack, 3,5 to a float then put it on the stack and know that :true: has a value of True.

Here's what I tried so far but isn't working the way its supposed to:

```
    #!/util/bin/python
import re
import shlex
stack = []

tokens = (
  ('STRING', re.compile('"[^"]+"')),  # longest match
  ('NAME', re.compile('[a-zA-Z_]+')),
  ('SPACE', re.compile('\s+')),
  ('NUMBERD', re.compile('\d.')),
  ('NUMBERI', re.compile('\d+')),
  ('TRUE', re.compile(':true:')),
  ('FALSE', re.compile(':false:')),
  )

def main ():


    while 1:
        inp = input('INPUT> ')
        push(inp,stack) #Push User Input unto stack
        printStack(stack) #Print Stack
        quit(inp,stack) #Exit program if prompted  




def push(s,list):
    tokens = shlex.split(s, posix=False)
    for token in tokens:
        if type(s) == 'NUMBERI':
            list.append(int(token))
        elif type(s) == 'NUMBERD':
            list.append(float(token))
        else:
            list.append(token)

    return list

def printStack(stack):
    for index in stack[::-1]:
        print (index)



def quit (x, stack):
    if x == "quit":
        stack.pop()
        exit(0)


def type(s):
    i = 0
    lexeme = []
    while i < len(s):
        match = False
        for token, regex in tokens:
            result = regex.match(s, i)
            if result:
                return(token)
                i = result.end()
                match = True
                break
        if not match:
            raise Exception('lexical error at {0}'.format(i))




def add (x,y):
    return(x + y)

def sub (x,y):
    return(x - y)

def mul (x,y):
    return(x * y)

def div (x,y):
    return(x / y)   


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), it safely evaluates a string as an expression.

Demo:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> a = literal_eval('5')
>>> b = literal_eval('3.5')
>>> c = literal_eval('True')
>>> [e, type(e).__name__ for e in (a, b, c)]
[(5, 'int'), (3.5, 'float'), (True, 'bool')]
```

Comment: Perfect! But how do I convert to lets say a float or int? @Alex Thornton

Comment: @MannyO I don't understand. They are automatically converted to their corresponding types as they are evaluated.

Comment: oh so they get converted and pushed unto the stack bound to their new type? @Alex Thornton

Comment: Because I tried that and im getting errors `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hw3.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "hw3.py", line 22, in main
    push(inp,stack) #Push User Input unto stack
  File "hw3.py", line 32, in push
    list.append(type(literal_eval(token)))
  File "/util/python/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 86, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/util/python/lib/python3.3/ast.py", line 85, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x2ac048d30290>`

Comment: I did this, is this the correct implementation?:
`def push(s,list):
 tokens = shlex.split(s, posix=False)
 for token in tokens:
   list.append(type(literal_eval(token)))
 return list` @Alex Thornton

Comment: @MannyO It should work fine as long as you are only using types in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: I am but its still doesn't work, can you try it youself using my code @Alex Thornton

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
push(str(inp),stack) #Push User Input unto stack
```